Configure clangd to reflect implicit dependency graph
P.S. I struggled to find an appropriate title for this question...
I am faced with a challenge when using clangd with the CPython project:

In the annotated screenshot shown above, macro PyObject_HEAD is defined inside "include/object.h". It is exposed to e.g. "cpython/funcobject.h" because object.h will always be included first. Note that "cpython/funcobject.h" does not have any includes itself (probably due to potential circular references).
The order of includes is ensured by "include/Python.h" - the API header. Hence the compiler works fine with it.
However, clangd will complain about this because it cannot figure out where to find the symbol. My current workaround is adding the following configuration for clangd:
# .clangd
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-include, /include/Python.h]

However, this creates a new potential issue. For example, "lock.h" (included on line 71) should not have access to macro PyObject_HEAD defined in "object.h" which is included later (line 72).
Also, the scope of this configuration is too large: clangd will apply this rule to all header and source files inside the project. Not all of them should be injected with this extra header.

Here comes the question:
Is there a more robust way to configure clangd so it precisely tracks the origin and availability of a symbol?
Please note: blaming the coding style is not an acceptable answer.


Is there a more robust way to configure clangd so it precisely tracks the origin and availability of a symbol?

There is not currently. This is a widely requested feature tracked in https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/45.
The ticket is open and available for someone interested in contributing a fix to take on. Note that the fix is somewhat involved, as discussed in the issue thread.

Thanks for pointing it out! I did not know what keyword to use for search hence did not find this open issue.
